# Existence of a player who defeated all others and a player who lost to all others in a table tennis tournament

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory

In a table tennis tournament (in which no game ends in a tie), each of the $n$ participants played exactly once against each of the others. It is known that for every $k>2$, there are no $k$ players $J_1, J_2, \ldots, J_k$ such that $J_1$ defeated $J_2, J_2$ defeated $J_3, J_3$ defeated $J_4, \ldots, J_{k-1}$ defeated $J_k, J_k$ defeated $J_1$.

Prove that there exists a player who defeated all the others, and there exists a player who lost to all the others.

**Attempt:**

Conjecture: For all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$, the statement is valid.

Let's represent the problem as a directed graph, where $\vec{j_1 j_2}$ indicates that $j_1$ defeated $j_2$.

Initial cases, $n=2, n=3$. Assume it holds for $k \in \mathbb{\geq3}$.

Thus, consider that we have vertices $j_1, j_2,..., j_k, j_{k+1}$ such that $OUT(j_1) \leq OUT(j_2) \leq OUT(j_3) \leq .... \leq OUT(j_{k+1})$.

Removing $j_{k+1}$ and its edges, we have by assumption in the new graph:
$$0 = OUT(j_1) \leq OUT(j_2) \leq OUT(j_3) \leq .... \leq OUT(j_{k})=k-1$$

Therefore, upon adding $j_{k+1}$ back, we have 2 cases.

Case 1) $OUT(j_{k+1})=k-1$

However, this implies that $j_{k+1}$ lost to $j_i \in {1, 2, \ldots, k}$.

If $i=1$
[image]

By hypothesis, this cycle cannot occur.

If $k>i>1$
[image]
By hypothesis, this cycle cannot occur.

If $i=k$, $OUT(j_k)=k> OUT(j_{k+1})$, which is absurd.

Therefore, only the second case remains, where $OUT(j_{k+1})=k$ and consequently $OUT(j_1)=0$.

I'm right?

Comment: This proof seems alright. It seems like the assumption of the question is a little too strong.

Comment: Alternative proof: suppose there is no universal loser, thus $\delta^+(v) \ge 1$ for all vertex of the tournament. Thus, there exist trivially a cycle: start from any vertex to move randomly among the one it beats. At some point you have to meet a vertex you've already traveled through. The exact same argument can be formulated for an universal winner.